# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken called for opted-out users?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to figure out the flow for push notifications if the users opts out. It seems to me that the push notification would be sent to the device, but the device would ignore them. Is that correct? All documentation talks only about the flow for opted in users.
(Basically, I was being asked whether opted out users' devices would still send a message to the Apple Server and the third-party (push notification) server, and it seems like they do in my testing)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience on my own device, yes.